# Conditionally allowing for null in LINQ WHERE clause

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lightspeed

### Working:

I am trying to perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN between my `Contacts` table and my `Permissions` table. I have the basis of this working correctly, and get back a list of contacts regardless of whether they have a corresponding permission.

```cs
// Query for Contacts
from contact in Contacts
join permission in Permissions on contact.Id equals permission.ObjectId into permissionGrp
from p in permissionGrp.DefaultIfEmpty()            
where p==null || (p!=null && /* ... condition based on the existence of a permission */)
select new { contact, permission = p };
```

Generated WHERE SQL:

```
WHERE
(t1.PermissionId IS NULL OR 
    ((t1.PermissionId IS NOT NULL AND ... other conditions ... )))
```

### Problem:

I want to adapt the above to introduce 'fallback' check; Not working as expected.

### Requirement:

- When there is no `Permission` corresponding to the `Contact` (i.e. `p==null`) then only include the row based on the predetermined `bool` value of `allowed`.

### Attempt:

I thought I could do `where (p==null && allowed) || ...` like this:

```cs
// Fallback permission
bool allowed = false;

// Query for Contacts
from contact in Contacts
join permission in Permissions on contact.Id equals permission.ObjectId into permissionGrp
from p in permissionGrp.DefaultIfEmpty()

/* Added bool condition 'allowed' to control inclusion when 'p' is null */
where (p==null && allowed) || (p!=null && /* ... condition based on the existence of a permission */)
select new { contact, permission = p };
```

### Expected:

#### When `allowed = false` (don't accept `null` permission)

```
WHERE
    ((t1.PermissionId IS NOT NULL AND ... other conditions ... ))
```

#### When `allowed = true`  (accept `null` permission)

```
WHERE
(t1.PermissionId IS NULL OR 
    ((t1.PermissionId IS NOT NULL AND ... other conditions ... )))
```

### Actual Result:

Always outputs as if `allowed=false` even when `true`?

```
WHERE
    ((t1.PermissionId IS NOT NULL AND ... other conditions ... ))
```

## Summary:

I hope I am just doing something silly that's easily fixed.
How can I filter my `null` value records based on a given `bool` value?

Comment: did you actually check the query result by running it or just try seeing the translated SQL query? Looks like somehow the `allowed` is always translated to `false`.

Comment: I have run the query in LinqPad which is where it showed the SQL output. It isn't returning the expected result set.

Comment: I've not used LINQPad much and just used some features of it but I think you should try your code in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is a bug in the ORM ([LightSpeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed)) I am using, which I will bring to their attention.

### Workaround

I have found a suitable work around, using the `let` clause.

```cs
// Fallback permission
bool allowed = false;

// Query for Contacts
from contact in Contacts
join permission in Permissions on contact.Id equals permission.ObjectId into permissionGrp
from p in permissionGrp.DefaultIfEmpty()

/* Work around for 'allowed' not being honoured properly, using 'let' */
let isAllowed = allowed

/* Added bool condition 'isAllowed' to control inclusion when 'p' is null */
where (p==null && isAllowed) || (p!=null && /* ... condition based on the existence of a permission */)
select new { contact, permission = p };
```

### Result

It is now using comparison of a known value with itself as a boolean check. In this case `t0.ContactId`.

#### SQL When `allowed=true` ... `t0.ContactId = t0.ContactId`

```sql
WHERE
    ((t1.PermissionId IS NULL AND t0.ContactId = t0.ContactId) OR 
     (t1.PermissionId IS NOT NULL AND ... other conditions ...))
```

#### SQL When `allowed=false` ... `t0.ContactId <> t0.ContactId`

```sql
WHERE
    ((t1.PermissionId IS NULL AND t0.ContactId <> t0.ContactId) OR 
     (t1.PermissionId IS NOT NULL AND ... other conditions ...))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a `GroupJoin` here. So the result of the first part, `permissionGrp`, is an anonymous type `IGrouping<Permission>`. This already is the eqivalent of an OUTER JOIN.

You can achieve what you want by conditionally testing whether or not the `IGrouping<Permission>` contains elements:

```
from contact in Contacts
join permission in Permissions on contact.Id equals permission.ObjectId
    into permissionGrp
where allowed || g.Any()
from p in permissionGrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { contact, permission = p };
```

Note that `from p in permissionGrp` flattens the grouping again, so `.DefaultIfEmpty()` is still necessary for the case where `allowed == true`.

Comment: Hi Gert, thanks for the answer. I can see what you are doing. Unfortunately I am getting an exception `Argument Exception: Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod`. I am think this may perhaps be a shortcoming of my ORM [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed). I'm going to try a few simpler tests to determine if it's the ORMs fault, which I suspect it is.